# Greedy subrules and LL(1) grammar in ANTLR4

Tags: parsing, antlr4

Suppose I have a grammar like this, and it's LL(1):
(Lexical rules ignored)

```
grammar parser_dfa;

drc_parser_start:layer_def derived_layer_def drc_rules;

layer_def: LAYER VAR_NAME NUM;

derived_layer_def:VAR_NAME ASSIGNMENT derived_op_statement;

derived_op_statement: r_and | r_or | r_not ;

r_and: AND op_layer op_layer;

r_or: OR op_layer op_layer;

r_not: NOT op_layer op_layer;

op_layer: LEFT_PAR derived_op_statement RIGHT_PAR | VAR_NAME ;

drc_rules: VAR_NAME_TWO LEFT_BRACKET derived_layer_def check_statement RIGHT_BRACKET;

check_statement: r_and | r_or | r_not ;
```

If I change rule drc_parser_start and drc_rules into this way:

```
drc_parser_start:layer_def* derived_layer_def* drc_rules*;
drc_rules: VAR_NAME_TWO LEFT_BRACKET (derived_layer_def | check_statement)* RIGHT_BRACKET;
```

is the whole grammar still in LL(1) style?

If so, how can I write the parsing table of this grammar?

Thank you.

================================================================
Edited:
@kaby76
I put full grammar on:

```
grammar parser_dfa;

drc_parser_start:layer_def* derived_layer_def* drc_rules*;

layer_def: LAYER VAR_NAME NUM;

derived_layer_def:VAR_NAME ASSIGNMENT derived_op_statement;

derived_op_statement: r_and | r_or | r_not ;

r_and: AND op_layer op_layer;

r_or: OR op_layer op_layer;

r_not: NOT op_layer op_layer;

op_layer: LEFT_PAR derived_op_statement RIGHT_PAR | VAR_NAME ;

drc_rules: VAR_NAME_TWO LEFT_BRACKET (derived_layer_def | check_statement)* RIGHT_BRACKET;

check_statement: r_and | r_or | r_not ;


LAYER:'LAYER';

NUM:  [1-9][0-9]* | '0' ;

AND: 'AND';

OR: 'OR' ;

NOT: 'NOT' ; 

LEFT_PAR:'(' ;

RIGHT_PAR: ')' ;

LEFT_BRACKET:'{';

RIGHT_BRACKET:'}';

VAR_NAME: [A-Za-z_]+ ;

ASSIGNMENT: '=' ;

WS: [ \t\r\n]+ -> channel(HIDDEN) ;

VAR_NAME_TWO:PART_ONE DOT PART_TWO DOT PART_THREE ;
fragment PART_ONE:[A-Za-z_]+ ;
fragment PART_TWO:[A-Za-z_]+ ;
fragment PART_THREE:[0-9]+ ;
fragment DOT: '.' ;
```

I'm just curious whether it's LL(1) or not in both situations(meaning that ANTLR4 subrule greedy symbol * in drc_parser_start and drc_rules enabled or not).If it's LL(1) with symbol * on, I wonder how to write the parsing table.

Comment: Doesn't that depend on being able to distinguish between a LAYER, a VAR_NAME & a VAR_NAME_TWO?

Comment: @ScottHunter In my lexical rules,LAYER,VAR_NAME & VAR_NAME_TWO're defined totally different. So is it still LL(1)? I wonder how to write parsing table of this grammar because it contains greedy symbol(* in the subrules of grammar) .

Comment: If no token can be more than one of LAYER, VAR_NAME & VAR_NAME_TWO, then the parser can tell if you are starting a new `layer_def`, `derived_layer_def` or a `drc_rules`.  If the same is true at your other decision points, you're good.

Comment: Please provide a full (apparently combined, not split) grammar so I can check using tool if it's still LL1.

Comment: @kaby76 I've pasted full grammar and my question in edited part of the question now.By the way, may I ask the name of your checking tool? Anyway, thank you for your comment and help. :)